# jQuery data() vs Objects (Performance)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am wondering which way is more efficient using jQuery data to bind data for object or using this kind of object. I am trying to create some kind of model for my app. Here is the object code

```
var PersonData = function () {
    var that = {},
        _name = 0,
        _age = 0.0,
        _domId = false;

    that.data = initData();

    //This is for initing data from options
    function initOptions () {
        return {
            name: _name,
            age: _age,
            domId: _domId
        }
    }

    that.setName = function (name) {
        that.data.name = name;
    }

    that.getName = function () {
        that.data.name;
    }

    // I forgot to add dom id, now there is id for binding
    that.setDomElementId = function (id) {
        that.data.domId = id;
    }

    //Add getters and setter

    return that;
}
```

Thanks for your opinions

By the way is there good plugin for generating getters and setters in textmate for javascript

Comment: Please reserve "by the way" questions for another question.

Comment: An idiom for a data structure with default properties would be: `function PersonData(name, age) { this.name = name || ""; this.age = age || 0; }` Though, with falsy defaults like this, I would just leave them undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `.data()` is for attaching data to DOM elements. If you're not touching the DOM, then don't touch `.data()`.

Also, I don't think the kind of encapsulation you're going for is worthwhile in JavaScript (*unless you require it to detect data read/writes*). **Especially** if you're concerned about performance, directly accessing objects' properties is a much better option. JavaScript is a dynamic language, embrace it :)

Comment: +1 For embracing the language's properties. I would have given another +1 if I could for decoupling data from presentation (DOM).

Comment: Damn, I forgot to add DOM id for object, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for encapsulation tip.

Comment: @user It really depends on how you want to access your objects. If you keep them in some JS array / object, then stick to what you have. If you want to be able to access them given a jQuery selector... then use jQuery's `.data()`. But performance-wise, direct property access is faster than a function call.